# Fluid in simulation disappears when from moving container

Tags: fluid-simulation

I have an animation of a mug filled with a liquid moving up then turning to spill out the liquid. The problem is, when the mug lifts, the amount of fluid within the mug decreases. The loss continues when the mug rotates. When the mug stops raising, the remaining half of the liquid flies out of the mug at high speed and appears to collide with an invisible plane even though the actual ground is much further below it. The other half stays suspended in the air within the mug.

[image: Download the .Blend]

Comment: @Tobmonst3r Are you animating the fluid simulation's location and the mug when it lifts up? You could just make the mug an obstacle, and animate the mug's location. Then the fluid would not be animated, you would avoid problems of it not colliding in the correct spots.

Comment: Sounds like an instancing problem to me. Either that or margins are messed up.

Comment: I am just animating the mug and baking the fluid.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is that scale has not been applied. The domain and the obstacles should have an euler scale of 1,1,1. Just select everything and press Ctrl+A and choose scale. Otherwise the fluid will misinterpret where the obstacles are and just act weird.

Another thing is that the domain is ridiculously large, so even with a high resolution you're basically getting crap, which means that the fluid will act strangely.