# Fluid dissapears while moving

Tags: fluid-simulation

I'm having a problem with [this simulation](https://youtu.be/mvFRFP9cp7E).

When the fluid starts to move it seems to lose mass and I don't understand why. If you compare the volume of the fluid at the beginning and the volume at the end its not the same.

Does anybody got an idea on how to fix this?

I'm working on Blender 2.92

Settings for the simulation.

[image: Here is the collider/effector info]

[image: This is the fluid info]

[image: And the domain info]

[image]

[image]

And here is the file

[image]

Comment: Share your file. https://blend-exchange.com

Comment: Without more information, we have to guess wildly. My guess is the liquid evaporates. You need to cool down the vertices ;-) Seriously, can you add more info? How is this fluid created, settings, etc?

Comment: @Blunder I edited the post with all the info and the project !!!  Thanks!

Comment: @R-800  I edited the post with all the info and the project !!! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's a **bug** [T84287: [Mantaflow] Fluid volume loss with moving obstacle](https://developer.blender.org/T84287)

The answer to this question [Fluid in simulation disappears when from moving container](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/50383/107598) also recommends applying the scale to the domain, obstacle, and the liquid. (But it doesn't help in this case)

(Side note: you have *Auto Keying* activated and your liquid object has unnecessary keyframes.)